# How can I pinpoint a syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, procedure, dbeaver

I can't pinpoint the syntax error in this simple procedure and it's driving me mad by this point.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS address_insert$$
CREATE PROCEDURE address_insert()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hoop.address);
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

WHILE counter < 5 DO 
SET i = i + 1;

INSERT INTO hoop.address (adr_id, address, city, country, created_at, lat, lng, updated_at, zip)
VALUES                   (i, CONCAT("Address-", i), "City", "United States", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, (SELECT RAND() * (68-60) + 60), (SELECT RAND() * (65-55) + 55), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "ZIPCODE"); 

SET counter = counter + 1; 
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Divide and qonquer, i.e. remove some of it. Is the problem still there?

Comment: Yep, I removed the insert and the select in declaration which seem to be fine... It's a very simple function so I have no idea what else could fail.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Keep removing until the error is found.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: "Yep, I removed the insert and the select in declaration which seem to be fine..." What does this mean? After you removed them it continued to error or it ran fine?

Comment: The procedure keeps failing, the insert is running fine outside of the procedure.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to make `adr_id` an SUTOINCREMENT column.... Or is it already?

Comment: Are you running this in the MySQL client, or phpMyAdmin, or some other programmatic interface? I tested what you showed in the MySQL client, and it does not have an error.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps you should initialize the i variable with the maximum adr_id, instead of a count.  Assuming that adr_id is a PK. But personally I prefere not to insert into a PK and let it AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: I'm running it in DBeaver. 

Figured out that the primary problem is that mysql somehow doesn't create my function at all. Which is weird, considering I have all privileges for creation in the database.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATEA]

Figured out that the primary problem is that mysql somehow doesn't create my function at all. Which is weird, considering I have all privileges for creation in the database. Any guesses why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

There's no syntax error in your code. I tested it with the MySQL client, and it works fine.

Then I downloaded DBeaver and tried your query. I found that I had to highlight all the lines in the query and then execute using Ctrl-Enter.

If I don't highlight all the lines, it seems to execute each line individually as a separate SQL statement, regardless of setting `DELIMITER`.

I will now uninstall DBeaver. It really doesn't seem like it's going to improve my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Add the previous delimiter after the statement setting the new delimiter:

`DELIMITER $$;`

`DELIMITER ;$$`